# multiprocessing in cases where the function got lots of arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

Any ideas on how to implement/call a function with a long range of arguments in multiprocessing's process pool or joblib where two or three parameters do change with each iteration the remaining stay the same.

Below is the loop (I need to run this in parallel): Please note here idx, string and secondaryf change only.

```
sep = ['These limits may help reduce', 'though not completely eliminate', 'alcohol related risks']

for idx, string in enumerate(sep):

    print "working on", string
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    folder = os.path.join(base_dir, folder)
    secondaryf = os.path.join(folder, str(idx))
    print "making", secondaryf

    if not os.path.exists(secondaryf):
        os.makedirs(secondaryf)

    number_of_lines = countlines2(string)

    words_2(string, secondaryf, fontface, fontface_italic, 
            number_of_lines, highlight, 
            highlight_color, font_color, 
            key_color, first_key, second_key, 
            third_key, stroke_color, 
            stroke_width, txt_under_color)
```

I know a bit about using joblib for multiple arguments but in my case not all parameters change. Previously I have used similar structures in one of my projects (just an example).

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

vertices = [100, 1000, 10000]
edge_probabilities = [.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6]
power_exponents = [2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4]
graph_types = ['Erdos_Renyi', 'Barabasi', 'Watts_Strogatz']

Parallel(n_jobs=6)(delayed(makeGraph)(graph_type=graph, nodes=vertex, edge_probability=prob, power_exponent=exponent) for vertex in vertices for prob in edge_probabilities for exponent in power_exponents for graph in graph_types)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `functools.partial` to fix the arguments that are not changing: Say you have a function `f(a, b, c, d, e)` and you only want to vary c and e. Then, you can get a function `f_partial(c, e)` by

```
f_partial = functools.partial(f, a=a_value, b=b_value, d=d_value)
```

Then, just use the pattern you used before for parallel jobs.

Comment: does this definitely work with joblib ? i seem to recall trying something like this once and it raised some errors related to pickling lambda functions or some such. although maybe I was trying this was with `multiprocessing`

Comment: I just checked on python3.6 that pickling partial objects works. Of course, you cannot pickle lambda functions in general (and hence not if you partial them).